# Change xcode description of a symbol popover's font

Tags: xcode

When I update to Xcode 8, 
The Quick Help popover's font with Option-Click symbol became too small and hard to read.
Can I change this font size bigger?
[The Quick Help popover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cq2a.png)

Comment: The logical place for this to be changed is in Xcode preferences -> Fonts & Colors, but there is no "Documentation" tab next to "Source Editor" & "Console" for font choice selection.  This would be a useful feature, and I recommend filing an enhancement request at http://bugreporter.apple.com

Comment: OK, I will try to filing an enhancement request at bugreporter.